# Xaml C# Appliction resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

привет есть код

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="style">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
```

записан в файл app.xaml
По работает только почему то Background 
Остальные стили не работают почему то что не так делаю
Кнопка

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource style}" Height="100" Width="300"/>
```

Comment: У меня ваш пример работает.

Comment: как так ваще..а

Comment: Обманул вас, заметил что не все стили подхватываются)

Comment: ну у вас же не только задний фон работает?

Comment: Добавил пример, как можно добиться желаемого результата, надеюсь, что вам поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы ваш пример заработал, вы должны полностью переопределить унаследованный стиль Windows для кнопок. В вашем случае, код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="style">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: спасибо  да работает